# Neat 2.0 in combination with Flexbox to align middle

Tags: css, flexbox, neat

I'm trying to use Neat 2.0 (to handle horizontal alignments) along with Flexbox (to handle vertical alignments).

What I'm trying to achieve is the middle content next to the image, followed by the next row. However, for some reason, everything gets put on the same row when I add `display: flex`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

**HTML (Slim)**

```
.container
  - 3.times do
    .col middle
  .col--image 
    img src='//placehold.it/700'
  - 3.times do
    .col next row
```

**SCSS**

```
@import "neat@2.*";

.container {
    @include grid-container;
    @include grid-visual; /* temp guide */
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex; /* adding this wrecks things */
    align-items: center;
}

.col {
  @include grid-column(2);
}

.col--image {
  @include grid-column(6);

  img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;    
  }
}
```

I have an [example codepen](https://codepen.io/skube/pen/gRGXvM/) too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `next row` to actually wrap, you need to add `flex-wrap: wrap`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgqXdp)

```
.container {
    @include grid-container;
    @include grid-visual;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;                      /* added property */
    align-items: center;
}
```